# AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'randit'

Tags: python, random

I have seen the answers/recommendations for this questions.

I promise that I do not have a random.py file named on my computer. I have searched it, tried to delete it will the send2trash module as well as os.unlink. I simply do not get it. I am unable to call the random.randit() because of this issue. Also when I call os.cwd() the file path does not exist on my computer. I again, have no idea how this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

The code would be random.randint(), not random.randit()